# breaking 'sleep' in perl abruptly

Tags: windows, perl, multiprocessing, signals, sleep

I want to do the following -

```
#starting code

sleep(1000);

#remaining code
```

The starting code would run and get stuck at 'sleep'. After some time (<<1000), some other process would wake up this process by breaking this sleep(probably by sending a signal) and the rest of the program would run.

I have to use perl 5.6.1 *on Windows*, and it doesn't support alarm. I tried some signals like SIGINT, SIGFPE etc. but failed. Please suggest some alternative.

Comment: Two things: 1. Upgrade your version of Perl. 2. Use threads.

Comment: @JackManey I would surely have done that but there are some constraints.

Comment: [There](https://metacpan.org/module/App::perlbrew) [are](https://metacpan.org/module/local::lib) [alternatives](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads).

Comment: What do you mean that you tried SIGINT, SIGFPE "but failed."  Failed how?

Comment: @jackmaney,@pilcrow: I think you still haven't read the question completely .......I HAVE to use v5.6.1.....  and my comment ....constraints..... from which anyone can deduce that there is something I am using which is dependent on v5.6.1. I said - the use of signals failed and I want some alternative - means that I expect you to answer only if you know some way other than SIGNALS. Perhaps you should spend more time thinking of a solution than commenting or downvoting some post.

Comment: No-one has to use Perl 5.6.1. If you're working somewhere that insists on using a version of Perl that is over ten years old then get a new job.

Comment: No, you don't **have** to use Perl 5.6.1.  Click on the links in my previous comment.  And I'll comment and downvote whenever I wish.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a signal handler? If not, `SIGINT` and its ilk will terminate your program.

```
my $parent_pid = $$;

# schedule interruption
if (fork() == 0) {
    sleep 5;
    kill 'INT', $parent_pid;
    exit;
}

# trivial signal handler so SIGINT doesn't terminate the program
$SIG{INT} = sub { };
my $n = sleep 1_000_000;
print "Slept for $n seconds.\n";
```

On Linux, perl 5.6.2, this gives the output:

```
Slept for 5 seconds
```

---

For that matter, I don't know why you say alarm isn't supported on Perl 5.6 (unless you're on Windows maybe?) Again, set a signal handler or your program will terminate.

```
$SIG{ALRM} = sub {};
alarm 5;
$n = sleep 1_000_000;
print "slept for $n seconds\n";
```

works fine on my Perl 5.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I wanted to emulate

```
$SIG{ALRM} = \&handle_alarm;
alarm(5);
...
sleep(10);
```

I'd start with

```
use Time::HiRes qw( time sleep );  # Optional

my $alarm = time + 5;
...
my $timeout = $alarm - time;
if ($timeout <= 0) {
   handle_alarm();
} else {
   my $to_sleep = 10;
   $to_sleep = $timeout if $timeout < $to_sleep;
   sleep($to_sleep);
}
```

Comment: I tried exactly the same thing a couple of days ago, it worked fine in v5.14 but not in v5.6. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @SiddharthGaur - "Didn't work" is not a built-in error message in any version of Perl.

Comment: @Siddharth Gaur, You are mistaken about the exactness of your effort. `time`, addition and subtraction worked equally well in 5.6 as in 5.14.

Comment: @Siddharth Gaur, I didn't use `alarm`. I specifically showed you how not to use `alarm`.